# Do you know if Science/Nature/PNAS accept review articles that are not invited and do not contain original research?

Tags: research-process, publications

I cannot find any policy on the matter through their websites.

Comment: What do their guides for authors say?

Comment: It couldn't hurt to write them an email and ask if they would be interested.

Answer (score 4):

Nature Review articles do not need to be invited. And review articles are often not "original research". Nature Reviews http://www.nature.com/reviews/index.html accepts these. So the answers to your questions are "yes" and "yes"

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @mankoff's answer, be aware that it is possible, and indeed common in some fields, to email an editor with an idea, or draft, of a review paper and ask if they'd like to "invite".